# The key is also the solution: a word puzzle

Tags: cipher

The following text is encrypted with its own key.

> Ip;g siyyiu el ytaik pl ej ygi dit el auillik =eyg pb zaazleyi jebhiuC

A hint for those that want it:

> The entire solution is a syntactically valid English sentence (barring any mistakes from the manual encryption).

Second hint:

> It has something to do with your computer. This method is the same as the way most people on here write it, at least for the most part, since my native tongue is not English. There is a 1 to 1 direct match between letters in the solution and in the encrypted text.

How did I encrypt this and what is the solution?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain this possible to answer with just the information provided?

Comment: I believe so. It might require some thinking. I'll add another hint, since I just realized that my situation is probably slightly different from most people on her (English is not my native language). There have been puzzles of a similar type before, but not as complicated.

Comment: Is it horizontal mirroring of the keyboard ?

Comment: Yes it is. now, use this to translate the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I manually deciphered it as a hinted symmetrical substitution cipher

> Each letter is typed as if the key is pressed with an opposite finger.

remark:

> Mark that the "." would be a ":" on most(?) keyboards, if I were to guess, your keyboard has the "." and the ";" on the same key. Mine has an ":" when I press SHIFT+";"

Yes, after checking images of an AZERTY keyboard, my suspicion is confirmed. Interestingly, those who see the "trick" may be put off by some letters being in non-standard positions for QWERTY-users.

Comment: I use an Azerty keyboard, so yes, the . and ; are on the same key. You are correct, and you are the first one to have given the complete answer in full. Mew already started to answer, but he was later than you with a completely correct answer.

Comment: @Mew: your answer was started earlier, but you didn't have the complete mesage before oerkelens answered with it.

Comment: @Mew this is a tricky situation. I both gave you an upvote, but you were so close together with your answer that you both equally deserve the accepted answer. I don't know how I'll handle this, because bounties are not the proper way to solve this either. I'll ask this on the Meta.

Comment: @Mew: if it is so important to you, yes, you beat me by two minutes and some, as I was actually deciphering the code manually, which lead to me including the colon. I certainly did not "just add a colon" to your answer, I gave my own. The colon is quite important, as it hinted at the "strange" keyboard. On my keyboard, the = and the W are not at all opposite each other either.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs: I was beaten fair and square by Mew - if you forgive him the period/colon omission. No problem with me if you accept his answer :)

Comment: I have decided to delete my solution to make the process easier.

Comment: Actually, you both have the same mistake, you and @Mew. The colon should be a period, since that's typed with shift and right middle finger on an Azerty keyboard (which is capital C with shift and left middle finger). If you edit that, I'll accept it. might be pedantic, but I'd rather do this properly.

Comment: Nothing wrong with being pedantic :)